# Convert an array into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, blackjack

I'm having a lot of trouble turning an array into an `ArrayList` in Java. This is my array right now:

```
Card[] hand = new Card[2];
```

"hand" holds an array of "Cards". How this would look like as an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Have you read any reference info, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As an `ArrayList` that line would be

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
...
ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

To use the `ArrayList` you have do

```
hand.get(i); //gets the element at position i 
hand.add(obj); //adds the obj to the end of the list
hand.remove(i); //removes the element at position i
hand.add(i, obj); //adds the obj at the specified index
hand.set(i, obj); //overwrites the object at i with the new obj
```

Also read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Thank you! One last quick question.. how would I accept an arraylist into a method? Right now I have:

public void getHandValue(ArrayList< Card > hand) {...}

The arraylist is in my main args. Just the word "ArrayList" is coming up as an error.

Comment: you should be able to have a method signature `void getHandValue(ArrayList<Card> hand)` the problem is more than likely when you are calling that method.

Answer (score 89):

This will give you a list.

```
List<Card> cardsList = Arrays.asList(hand);
```

If you want an arraylist, you can do

```
ArrayList<Card> cardsList = new ArrayList<Card>(Arrays.asList(hand));
```

Comment: Nope! This gives an object that acts as a `List` wrapper around an underlying object. Unlike a real `ArrayList`, the resulting `List` is not resizable, and attempts to `.add` elements to the end of it will result in `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 15):

```
List<Card> list = new ArrayList<Card>(Arrays.asList(hand));
```

Answer (score 1):

declaring the list (and initializing it with an empty arraylist)

```
List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

adding an element:

```
Card card;
cardList.add(card);
```

iterating over elements:

```
for(Card card : cardList){
    System.out.println(card);
}
```